# PHP MySql query: Split into parts with regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM mytable
WHERE col1 = :col1
```

Or I have:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM mytable
WHERE col1 = :col1 
ORDER BY col2 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Or I have:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM mytable
GROUP BY col1
```

An so on...

How do I split this into a **first** part (SELECT-Part, FROM-Part, WHERE-Part, ...) and in a **second** part with evertything after the first part.

I know, doing regex on SQL ist evil. It's better not to do this. Nevertheless I would like to see the regex, which can solve that.

Comment: You are given a sql string and you need to figure out what it wants to query, or you need to dynamically build the query based one php variables?

Comment: You're basically developing an SQL parser. Where are these queries coming from? If you're building them yourself, why not build them in such a way that you can easily decompose them again? There's zero point in baking a cake and then trying to extract the flour/milk/eggs from the cake after the fact.

Comment: I think it would be very important for this question if we knew what your ultimate goal was

Comment: `preg_match()` is the function you need to execute regex, please post the code of the regex you tried!

Comment: I have learned, that modifiing a SQL-Statement with regex is not a good idea. So right now I just want to know, how the right regex looks like, because I didn't figure out yet: `preg_match('/(.+?)(((GROUP BY)|(ORDER BY)|(LIMIT)).+?)/Uis', $sql, $matches)`